# How to write jQuery prependTo for the result I want?

Tags: jquery

I have a question about jQuery prependTo.

This is the html framework, and I can't change the framework.

```
<section class="press-item">
  <h2 class="press-title">press title 1</h2>
  <div class="press-author">Fraser Hughes</div>
  <div class="press-publisher">Evening Times</div>
  <time class="press-date" pubdate="">October 19, 2012</time>
  <div class="press-preview">press contain 1</div>
  <a class="press-more" href="" target="_blank">Read More</a> 
</section>

<section class="press-item">
  <h2 class="press-title">press title 1</h2>
  <div class="press-author">Fraser Hughes</div>
  <div class="press-publisher">Evening Times</div>
  <time class="press-date" pubdate="">October 19, 2012</time>
  <div class="press-preview">press contain 1</div>
  <a class="press-more" href="" target="_blank">Read More</a> 
</section>
</code>
```

I want to add a `<p></p>` to wrap .press-autho, .press-publisher and press-date. 
The result should be like this:

```
<section class="press-item">
  <h2 class="press-title">press title 1</h2>
  <p>
    <div class="press-author">Fraser Hughes</div>
    <div class="press-publisher">Evening Times</div>
    <time class="press-date" pubdate="">October 19, 2012</time>
  </p>
  <div class="press-preview">press contain 1</div>
  <a class="press-more" href="" target="_blank">Read More</a> 
</section>

<section class="press-item">
  <h2 class="press-title">press title 1</h2>
  <p>
    <div class="press-author">Jeff Drake</div>
    <div class="press-publisher">Houston Chronicle</div>
    <time class="press-date" pubdate="">October 29, 2012</time>
  </p>
  <div class="press-preview">press contain 2</div>
  <a class="press-more" href="" target="_blank">Read More</a> 
</section>
```

However, The result became like this

```
    <section class="press-item">
      <h2 class="press-title">press title 1</h2>
      <p>
        <div class="press-author">Fraser Hughes</div>
        <div class="press-author">Jeff Drake</div>
        <div class="press-publisher">Evening Times</div>
        <div class="press-publisher">Houston Chronicle</div>
        <time class="press-date" pubdate="">October 19, 2012</time>
        <time class="press-date" pubdate="">October 29, 2012</time>
      </p>
      <div class="press-preview">press contain 1</div>
      <a class="press-more" href="" target="_blank">Read More</a> 
    </section>

    <section class="press-item">
      <h2 class="press-title">press title 1</h2>
      <p>
        <div class="press-author">Jeff Drake</div>
        <div class="press-publisher">Evening Times</div>
        <div class="press-publisher">Houston Chronicle</div>
        <time class="press-date" pubdate="">October 19, 2012</time>
        <time class="press-date" pubdate="">October 29, 2012</time>
      </p>
      <div class="press-preview">press contain 2</div>
      <a class="press-more" href="" target="_blank">Read More</a> 
    </section>
```

My code is

```
$(function () {
    var sources$ = $('<p class="post-listmeta"></p>'),
        targets$ = $('.press-title'),
        operation = 'after';
    targets$[operation](sources$);
    $('.press-publisher').prependTo($('.post-listmeta'));
    $('.press-author').prependTo($('.post-listmeta'));
    $('.press-date').prependTo($('.post-listmeta'));

});
```

How do I writ the code that could be the result that I want?

Thank you every one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work section-by-section:

```
$("section.press-item").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".press-author, .press-publisher, .press-date").wrapAll("<p>");
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ufotel/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ufotel/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$($('section')[0]).find('.press-title,.press-author,.press-publisher').wrapAll('<p/>');
```

Here **$('section')[0]** will return the first section (you can loop around to do the same for more such sections), then you've to lookup the elements you want to be wrapped with **.find('.press-title,.press-author,.press-publisher')**, then **wrapAll** will do the rest of the job.